# Remove duplicates with nested loops java

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am trying to develop a program that can sort through a String and remove the duplicates. I am using nested loops for this. However when i run my code it just repeats a few words over and over.

```
package q2;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";
    String lowercaseSentence;
    lowercaseSentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
    String[] sentenceWords = lowercaseSentence.split(" ");
    int LenghtofSentence = sentenceWords.length;
    String[] unique = new String[LenghtofSentence];

    for (int i = 0; i <= LenghtofSentence; i++) {
        //System.out.println(i);
        for (int j = 0; j <= LenghtofSentence; j++) {
            if (!sentenceWords[i].equals(unique)) {
               unique[j] = sentenceWords[i];
               j++;
            } else {
                j++;
            } 
         }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unique));
   }
} 
}
```

This is the error message i am getting:

```
[ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask]
[not, null, not, null, not, null, not, null, not, null, not, null, not, null, not, null, not]
[what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what]
[your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your]
[country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country]
[can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can]
[do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do]
[for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for]
[you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you]
[ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask, null, ask]
[what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what, null, what]
[you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you, null, you]
[can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can, null, can]
[do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do, null, do]
[for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for, null, for]
[your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your, null, your]
[country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country, null, country]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17
```

I am using Netbeans for this. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Keir

Comment: Why don't you just use a  `Set` (e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`)?

Comment: When you write a `for` loop like this: `for (int i = 0; i <= LenghtofSentence; i++)` you are going past the end of your array. It should be `<` instead of `<=` .

Comment: `sentenceWords[i].equals(unique)` <- You are comparing a String (sentenceWords[i])  with an array of Strings (unique). They will never be equal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 package test;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test {


      public static void main(String[] args) {

          String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN  DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";

          String lowercaseSentence;

          lowercaseSentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

          String[] sentenceWords = lowercaseSentence.split(" ");

          int LenghtofSentence = sentenceWords.length;

          String[] uniqueString = new String[LenghtofSentence];

           ArrayList<String> unique = new ArrayList<String>();

          int k=0;
          for(int i=0;i<LenghtofSentence;i++)
          {
             if(!unique.contains(sentenceWords[i]))
             {
                unique.add(sentenceWords[i]);
                 k++;
             }
          }
          for(int i=0;i<unique.size();i++)
          {
              uniqueString[i] = unique.get(i);
              System.out.print(" "+uniqueString[i]);
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why you are using for loop for this and making it complex.

It can be done simply using `Set` in java. `Set` is a collection which contains no duplicate elements. For more [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(sentenceWords));
```

This will automatically remove the duplicates. You can get back your array without duplicates from `Set` as follows:

```
String[] unique = myset.toArray(new String[myset.size()]);
```

Also import following before using above code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

Using `LinkedHashSet` will keep the order in which the words were present in the array. Hope it helps.

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve word order.

Answer (score 0):

Give that your question seems an exercise, I think we shouldn't give you a solution but a suggestion that explain how to find a solution. First, if you can use Java collections in your exercise, use `Set<String>` would give you an improvement because it will check if a word is duplicated and give you a set without duplicates.

If in your exercise you can use only arrays, you have to use a different solution. 
I suggest to first iterate on the `unique` array in order to check if there are duplicates and then sort the `unique` array.

On the other hand Netbeans let you to execute your code step by step (as @f1sh suggested).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your logic is not looks perfect.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBound` is occur because of wrong indexing of arrays `unique` & `sentenceWords` replace `<=`  with `<` in both the loops because the length of array is a number of elements in the array & indexing starts from 0.

As I said before you should think about your logic again as it is not perfect. You can use following trick to accomplish your goal.

Replace the following code with the your code to remove duplicates & sort the array..

```
String[] unique = Arrays.stream(sentenceWords)
    .distinct().sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
```

After the execution of this statement the array `unique` contain distinct elements of the array `sentenceWords` in sorted form in lexical order. For more details refer javadocs.